# Install gcc/g++ 6 on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: gcc, 21.04

I am trying to compile Cuda 10.2 and predictably gcc-10 will not work to compile it. When using 20.04 it was simple, add bionic repo, update, install, update-alternatives. Using 21.04 I cannot get anything to work.

I tried with both xenial and bionic 'main' and 'universe' repos, which throws an error about the PUBKEY. I got the PUBKEYs from the ubuntu keyserver and update the package list, no errors.

```
sudo apt install g++-6

Package g++-6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'g++-6' has no installation candidate
```

sources.list ->

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute restricted main multiverse universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates restricted main multiverse universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security restricted main multiverse universe

# gcc-6
deb [allow-insecure=yes] http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe
#deb [allow-insecure=yes] http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this using Ubuntu 21.04? Every post I have read says to add the bionic or xenial repos, update, install. I have had no luck so far.

Comment: Just a heads-up... I went to [the CUDA website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.2-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu), and it does not list 21.04 as a version you can download. I suggest instead [downloading CUDA 11.4](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04), which at least supports 20.04. You could see if it works in 21.04. I don't know.

Comment: Also, I think you have [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1081494). If you tell us _why_ you want CUDA 10.2, and why you want to compile it yourself, we can try to help.

Comment: I am installing CUDA 10.2 in an lxc to run some object detection software. I ended up grabbing most of the packages and installing manually.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed the packages (.deb) I needed from browsing the Ubuntu repos [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gcc-6).

Here is a list of the .deb packages I needed to manually install gcc/g++ 6. Install in the order of the list. This assumes you have most of the tools needed to compile and are just looking to switch default gcc versions.

```
sudo apt install ./libisl19_0.19-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./gcc-6-base_6.4.0-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./cpp-6_6.4.0-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb

# you can grab this next package from 21.04 repos, it handles a lot of the dependancies.
sudo apt install libgcc-6-dev

# Finally
sudo apt install ./gcc-6_6.4.0-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb

# GCC-6 is now installed, you can test by gcc-6 -v
baudneo@ZMES-test:~$ gcc-6 -v
gcc version 6.4.0 20180424 (Ubuntu 6.4.0-17ubuntu1)

# Now for G++ 6
sudo apt install ./libstdc++-6-dev_6.4.0-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./g++-6_6.4.0-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb

# G++-6 is now installed! test by g++-6 -v
baudneo@ZMES-test:~$ g++-6 -v
gcc version 6.4.0 20180424 (Ubuntu 6.4.0-17ubuntu1)

# Now it is time to configure the system to use GCC G++ 6
# This assumes you do not have other versions of gcc and g++ installed for other projects

sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc 
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 100
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 100
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
# When you want to revert these back to default gcc-10
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc 
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 100
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 100
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
```

Comment: that link is showing 
Error

two or more packages specified (gcc-6 bionic)