# Install gcc/g++ 6 on Ubuntu 20.1

Tags: gcc, 20.10

I'm trying to install  gcc/g++ 6.

I have tried to modify sources.list and adding:

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe
```

However this method does not work.

Another method described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370373/install-gcc-g-6-on-ubuntu-21-04) seemed incredibly promising however I could not find the packages (.deb) I needed and the link provided no longer seems to work.

A complete solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 1):

First, to purely try to answer your question:

The .deb may not always be the best choice when you try to install an old version.

I think you should maybe install a newer version of it and use it to compile the older version from its sources:
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/releases/tag/releases%2Fgcc-6.4.0

Nb: C++ related features are under libstdc++-v3/ folder (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871383/where-can-i-download-the-source-code-to-the-gnu-c-standard-library)

For the .deb, I manage to find the g++-7 version: https://packages.debian.org/buster/g++-7 but not older in official archives.

Now, you ask for g++-6 but we may ask "why".
Depending on the reason, trying to install it directly may not be the best solution and giving us further informations would help us help you.

For example, you may use a docker image already containing the g++-6 version you need (e.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/camisa/powerdevs_devel/tags). Just mount the sources and build there.
(Alternatively, you could still try to find a debian based image with g++-6 inside and with the apt cache still containing the .deb, but this would take long to find and it is still certainly not the best solution for you).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need it for the same reasons explained https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370373/install-gcc-g-6-on-ubuntu-21-04 compiling the ready available source could be tricky I think as I have not done more than use gcc to compile very simple code a long time ago.